# redirect different url with the same subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, multisite

I am on a wordpress multisite.

I have old urls with the same subfolder name now i have to redirect old url to a new url with new subfolder name.

Example (will be simpler)

Old url 1 to new url 1:

`http://site1.fr/fr-chauffage.html`  to
`https://www.site1.fr/installation_chauffage`

Old url 2 to new url 2:

`http://site2.fr/fr-chauffage.html` to `https://www.site2.fr/installateur_chauffage_dans_ma_region`

So I wrote the following htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.fr
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.site1.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr-chauffage.html$ /installation_chauffage/ [R=301,NC,L]
 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.fr
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.site2.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fr-chauffage.html$ /installateur_chauffage_dans_ma_region/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

The trouble is whatever the website the user is always redirect to site1 + good_subfolder

If I have 3 websites with the same subfolder name the user will be always redirected to site1 + good_subfolder of the new url ...

Comment: How many different domains resolve here? If you are redirecting all domains to `www` and are not using other subdomains then you don't need to explicitly list the domains (as I have done in my answer) to redirect to `www`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The trouble is whatever the website the user is always redirect to site1 + good_subfolder

Because the `RewriteCond` directive only applies to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. The two subsequent `RewriteRule` directives are executing *unconditionally*.

You need to repeat the condition for all rules where it needs to apply.

You're directives are also in the wrong order - you need to have the more specific rules first, otherwise you will get multiple redirects. Currently, you are redirecting *everything* in your first rule. And then you have a more specific redirect later.

So, are *all* incoming requests less the `www` prefix (as suggested in your examples and directives)?

Try the following instead:

```
# Common rules for both sites
# (Although this will result in 2 redirects if requesting the non-canonical hostname)
RewriteRule ^fr\.html$ / [R=301,L]

# Site 1 rdirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr-chauffage.html$ https://www.site1.fr/installation_chauffage/ [R=301,NC,L]

# Site 2 rdirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr-chauffage.html$ https://www.site2.fr/installateur_chauffage_dans_ma_region/ [R=301,NC,L]

# non-www to www redirect - both sites
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(site1\.fr|site2\.fr) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```